# Which is the better approach if I want my code to be efficient

Tags: php, coding-efficiency

I didn't go to school when I started learning to code. I read books and browse the web. And this question really didn't appear in any of the books I read. And if I search it online I don't know what to search so I apologize in advance if this is obvious to you because it isn't to me.

Anyway is this approach better if I want my code to be efficient:

```
if($a == $b && $a <= $c && strlen($a) > 100 && functionA($a) && functionC($c)){
     //win
} else {
    //fail
}
```

**OR**

is this better:

```
if($a != $b){
    //fail
} elseif($a > $c) {
    //fail
} elseif(strlen($a) < 100){
    //fail
} elseif(!functionA($a)){
    //fail
} elseif(!functionC($c)){
    //fail
} else {
    //win
}
```

In javascript, I see compilers mash code up and eliminate all white space as possible and change variable names to a single letter (e.g. `thisname` to `a`) etc. In my understanding they do it so that the size of the javascript file is so small that when the page asks for it, loading time wouldn't be a problem.

But how about for `php` files? Which of the code above is better if I want my code to be efficient? why? **AND** Does the javascript scenario apply to php? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be focusing on efficiency at this level of your code, because its a micro-optimisation: readability is far more important in the real world

Comment: PhP is a programming language... i suggest you to use variable name that will display the "content" of them. This way you can (some time later) do not need to re-study all of your web-app to learn what's inside it. That said i think that even a Javascript file need to do this, not use 1 letter vars but use vars that clarify something. IMHO.

Comment: @MarkBaker So the codes above doesn't have that much of a difference?

Comment: And PHP doesn't equate to javascript in terms of minimising spacing and length of variable names, because the PHP code isn't transmitted across the internet between the server and the browser... and typically even javascript is written with meaningful variables names and spaces, and only minified for transmission

Comment: readability is 2nd pattern

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for performance metrics instead of just trying the code and getting those metrics for your particular setup.

Comment: At this point it's really not about efficiency when it comes to running the code but for you, and someone else, to understand the code and make it be as readable as possible. Also use proper variable names that make sense and don't use hard coded magic numbers / strings, like 100.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how do I get those metrics?

Comment: @Deadpool - tools like xdebug with win/kcachegrind can give you details of the actual performance of the code, or even simply starting a timer before and calculating the time difference after; but you'd be hard pushed to find any significant efficiency difference in these code examples even over thousands of iterations

Comment: @Deadpool - but I repeat, readability is far more important than efficiency in cases like this where the timing difference of one over the other is only measurable in picoseconds

Comment: to add to @MarkBaker's point, worry about this if you already notice bottlenecking on this code. If you don't, you're wasting time with "optimizing" when there's nothing to optimize. Go spend that time on feature development and bug fixing instead.

Comment: Readability is better if the timing difference is very very small! Got it! thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, efficiency is the least of your concerns here, readability and thereby maintainability are more important. Typically you'd use a *fail early* approach to achieve this:

```
function myTest($a, $b, $c) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($c < 10) {
        return false;
    }
    if (...) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively you may want to be throwing specific exceptions or return specific error codes instead of merely returning `false` to signal exactly what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say readability is most important factor, you won't win any speed anyway - compilers are quite smart.

```
if (passesRequirements($a, $c)) {
    //win
}

function passesRequirements($a, $b)
{
    return isNotEqual($a, $b)
        && isLargerThan($a, $b)
        && isShorterThan($a, 100);
}

function isShorterThan($str, $amount)
{
    return strlen($str) < $amount;
}
```

and so on.